# Как при oбработкe исключений и поиске строки с ошибкой воспользоваться exc_info()?

Tags: python

Для решения вопроса о поиске строки с ошибкой, англоязычные коллеги предлагают следующее решение:

```
import sys    
try:
    строка с ошибкой
except IndexError:
    #  Python 3
    print("Error on line {}".format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
```

Все работает прекрасно. Однако, нет пояснения о том, что это такое

```
sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno
```

Как я понял, метод `exc_info()` - это кортеж, а `[-1]` - это предпоследний индекс этого кортежа.

Не понятно, что за объект `tb_lineno` и что эти ребята делают все в общей связке.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в этой строке.

Comment: Всё есть в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)

Comment: sys.exc_info() - возвращает кортеж из трех значений, которые дают информацию об исключениях, обрабатывающихся в данный момент.

Comment: Да, все совершенно верно. Я читал эту документацию. Но там общая информация. А здесь применяется конкретный прием, значение которого мне совсем не ясно

Comment: Что именно в этой строке не ясно? Там есть [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#traceback-objects) на описание traceback objects, где написано, что такое `tb_lineno`. Если непонятно, что такое `[-1]`, то надо задать это отдельным вопросом (поискать дубликаты, такой вопрос не раз задавался)

Comment: [-1] - это предпоследний элемент кортежа или списка. Это я понимаю. Если только здесь не имеется в виду что-то другое. Мне не понятна эта строчка в целом. Например, когда вы пишете traceback.print_exc() то тут все ясно: в пространстве имен traceback вызывается метод print_exc() и делает то, для чего он предназначен. А в той строчке что - не пойму

Comment: [`print((1, 2, 3)[-1])`](https://repl.it/repls/IndolentPitifulPhase) печатает 3, а не 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если хотите разобраться, то разбейте решение на части. Присвойте новой переменной значение

```
x = sys.exc_info()[-1]
print(x)
```

Посмотрите на тип значения:

```
print(type(x))
```

Проверьте какие атрибуты и методы есть у данного объекта:

```
print(dir(x))
```